# TYPO3 Extbase: Sorted child objects with iterator.sort return 'NULL' on reloading

Tags: iterator, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a strange issue on vhs viewHelper iterator.sort:

The first time it works like a charm: child elements are displayed sorted by startdate.But when I reload the page iterator.sort returns 'Null', item.child is empty. After flushing the system cache it works the first time the page is loaded, but after reload: the same problem.

```
<f:for each="{item.child->v:iterator.sort(order: 'ASC', sortBy: 'startdate')}" as="childelement" iteration="childiterator">
    <f:debug inline='true'>{childelement}</f:debug>
</f:for>
```

{item.child} shows the expected elements, but as soon as I try to sort them with v.iterator.sort they disappear when I reload the page.

So **this** works every time (wrong order of course):

```
<f:for each="{item.child}" as="childelement" iteration="childiterator">
    <f:debug inline='true'>{childelement}</f:debug>
</f:for>
```

The plugin is configured as non-cachable.

TYPO3 7.6.16
vhs 4.1.0

Has anyone any ideas or experienced that problem and found a solution? Thanks!

Comment: seems to be a bug: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/1270

Comment: This didn't have any effect for the childelements:

    protected $defaultOrderings = array(
        'anyfield' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
        'childlement.anyfield' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
    );

I'll check again, but as far as I remember it only effects the sorting of the parent items. 

The fix in the bugreport mentioned above fixes the issue for vhs, I guess it will be in vhs in one of the next releases.

Comment: Using dot notation only sorts the parent by the child element. It does not sort the child elements. So far the best way to sort child elements is using the fix mentioned above.

Comment: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/pull/1271

Comment: Removed my comment about sorting by child objects. You're right of course; defining a sort by children has no effect because whats being sorted are the objects of the repository queried, not their children elements.